# targeting class inside class in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a unordered list like the following. When I hover on the list Log In, the text was hiding so i did the following css to prevent it

```css
li.nyan a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li class="nyan" style="background-color: #00bfff; "><a href="#">Log In</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="sss"><a href="admin">Admin</a></li>
      <li><a href="members">Member</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

now when i hover on the child drop downs "admin" and "member", its hiding the log in text again, so i wanted to make the font color of text white when i hover on child dropdowns, i did something like this

```css
li.sss a:hover {
  li.nyan {
    color: #fff !important;
  }
}
```

i know its not correct, am not good in css, can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: I don't understand, when I run your code, it does show that the Login, Admin and Member appears in white font.

Comment: @Gosi, because of some css conflict in the ready made template i am using, i need to know if there is any way to do it forcefuly adding inline styles :)

Comment: As above, the code you've provided works fine (other than the syntactically wrong last example). If it's not working for you then there's likely to be some other CSS interfering with yours. However we can't help with that without seeing it.

Comment: `i need to know if there is any way to do it forcefuly adding inline styles` Yes, there is. However it's literally the worst way to fix whatever your problem is. Use selector precedence to override instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please tell me how to do it coz i am new to css,

Comment: I would if I could, but as I said previously, you've not provided us with enough information on exactly what the problem is, or what's causing it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the css of the template, its like sea, i was not able to find  it so i just tried to do it inline, can you help me if i provide the live website, https://teia.website/teia

Comment: Just wrap your first `<ul` which contains everything with an `id`. Then write the css for that particular ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this you need to add one class to second ul `link-color` using that selector you need update the color. Check Snippet.

```css
li.nyan:hover > a
{
  color: #fff !important;
}

ul >  li > .link-color > li a:hover
{
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li class="nyan" style="background-color: #00bfff; "><a href="#">Log In</a>
    <ul class="link-color">
      <li class="sss"><a href="admin">Admin</a></li>
      <li><a href="members">Member</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad that helped.